# Removing right trailing slash from variable

Tags: jmeter

I'm starting to experiment with  JMeter. I have a test plan which makes an HTTP  Request  and I can retrieve a value from the response using the JSON extractor.  My issue is the value points to a URL which  has a trailing slash, like

```
https://www.example.com/
```

If I pass this value on to the next HTTP request I get the response

```
Non HTTP response code: java.net.MalformedURLException,Non HTTP response message: Illegal character found in host: '/'
```

this is not a valid URL to get to the next HTTP request because of  the trailing /.  What is the  best way to remove it?  This value could change on each thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have `/` character in the "Server Name or IP" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, either put the whole variable into "Path" field:

[image]

Or (better) using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) split it into protocol, host, port and path like:

```
def url = new URL(vars.get('your variable from JSON Extractor here'))

sampler.setProtocol(url.getProtocol())
sampler.setDomain(url.getHost())
sampler.setPort(url.getPort())
sampler.setPath(url.getPath())
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I did something similar but I like this approach better.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring inside [groovy function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to remove last character (/)

```
${__groovy(vars.get("myVar").substring(0\,vars.get("myVar").length-1))}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.

My var comes out of a JSON extractor in a previous step.  when I use this function, which I assume I can put into the serevrname/ip field of the next HTTP request, it behaves like it can't find my var.  if I put my var in the field as ```${myVar}```, the substitution gets done.  But not with the function. the url comes out as http://path, with no value for myVar.  

Incidentally, if myVar includes the ```https://```, is jmeter gonna barf?

Comment: @chrishare I guess you have https also in protocol field